# Correct way to structure a table in MySQL, to ensure 2 users checked the document?

Tags: mysql

**Details:**

I have 3 tables.

- Users
- Request
- Verify

See this fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac7c95d/1

**Note:**

The fiddle link is just a draft - it probably needs good re-structuring.

**Goal:**

I am unsure how to create a correct structure to achieve the following:

- 1 user requests their file to be reviewed.
- 2 other users, must verify the requested document.
- If both users have verified it as 'Done' mark as 'Completed'.
- If both users have verified as 'Not Done' mark as 'Rejected'.
- If 1 user verified it as 'Done' and the other user 'Not Done' it will be verified as 'Re-Mark'.

**Question**

What is a good way to structure this into MySQL? What would you recommend adding in?

**My solution, but I think there is something better than this:**

I think for the `Request` table - I can structure it this way:

```
create table request_label_signoff (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    date_requested timestamp,
    user_id int,
    filename varchar(255),
    verify_id_user1 int,
    progress_user1 int,
    verify_id_user2 int,
    progress_user2 int,
    foreign key(verify_id_user1) references verify(id),
    foreign key(verify_id_user2) references verify(id)
);
```

Comment: That strikes me as not even being 1NF given that you have in essence repeating fields `verify_id_user1` and `verify_id_user2`. There is a many to many relationship between a Request and a User who verifies the Request and a row in perhaps the Verify table (but not as you currently define it) should express that relationship. If I were to ask "What are all the user ids that have ever verified requests for user id 'xxx'?" think how clumsy your query would be. What if tomorrow you required N verifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do

```
create table request (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    date_requested timestamp,
    user_id int,
    filename varchar(255),
    status enum('new','verified','rejected') not null default 'new',
    foreign key(user_id) references user(id)
);

create table verify (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    user_id int,
    request_id int,
    created timestamp,
    status enum('verified','rejected') not null default 'new',
    foreign key(request_id) references request(id)
);
```

The if want to update the status of the request, can just do

```
update request 
inner join (select request_id,count(*) as users from verify where status = 'verified' group by verify having users>1) t2
    on (request.id = request_id) 
set request.status = 'verified'
where request.status = 'new';

update request 
inner join (select request_id,count(*) as users from verify where status = 'rejected' group by verify having users>1) t2
    on (request.id = request_id) 
set request.status = 'rejected'
where request.status = 'new';
```

Or can just filter the requests at query time (without having to 'maintain' a column in the request table.

```
select request.*,count(*) as verified from request  
inner join verify on (request.id = request_id and status = 'verified')
group by request_id
having verified>1
```

Or can find unverified items (to review!

```
select request.*,count(*) as processed from request  
inner join verify on (request.id = request_id)
group by request_id
having processed<2
```

ie any request, with less that two rows in verify.

Although it doesnt deal with one accept, and one reject!. to make sure get at least two of either reply

```
select request.*,count(*) as processed from request  
inner join verify on (request.id = request_id)
group by request_id,verify.status
having processed<2
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for an asnwer! Just noticed in your 2nd create table. Was you meant to create the `verify reference`?

Comment: when using the update - I get this error message: `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Opps, yes, need to a alias for the subquery. And yes did mean request_id! Edited the post :)